# state .cancelled called automatic while pinching - swift

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uigesturerecognizer, gesture

Im doing pinch gesture in a Image to scale the image , but while I'm pinching the image it first calls .began then sometimes .changed and finally .cancelled . I dont understand how the .cancelled state is being called while Im still pinching . Here is my code :

```
@objc
    func handlePinch(sender : UIPinchGestureRecognizer){
        
        if(sender.state == .began || sender.state == .changed) && parent.resizeActive{
          
            let lastScale = parent.lastScale
            let scale = sender.scale
            
            parent.currentScale = (scale - 1) + lastScale
            

            if(parent.currentScale > 3){
                parent.currentScale = 3
                }
            if(parent.currentScale <= 1){
                parent.currentScale = 1
                parent.lastScale = 1
                parent.offset = .zero
                
                }
        }
        else if sender.state == .ended && parent.resizeActive {
            parent.lastScale = parent.currentScale
            if(parent.currentScale <= 1){
                parent.offset = .zero
                parent.lastOffset = parent.offset
                                        }
        }
        
        if(sender.state == .began){
            print("Gesture Began")
        }
        if(sender.state == .changed){
            print("Gesture Changed")
        }
        if(sender.state == .ended){
            print("Gesture Ended")
        }
        if(sender.state == .cancelled){
            print("Gesture Cancelled")
        }
        
        setOffsetWidth()
        setOffsetHeight()
        //print(parent.currentScale)
    }
```